# How to add custom javascript function to Durandal

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am currently using the Durandal framework to build a simple site (my first with Durandal) and have a question on how to go about adding a simple javascript function.  I want to call the function after the DOM loads, but am not sure how to attach it to the current viewmodel. The problem I am having is the function is being called before the DOM loads and the div ID hasn't been created yet, which in this case is "sb-search".

I then tried adding the function to the viewmodel:

```
define(["plugins/router"], function (router) {

var vm = {
        viewAttached: viewAttached
    };

    return {
        router: router
    };

    function attached() {
        new UISearch(document.getElementById('sb-search'));
    }

    return vm;

});
```

but, to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Even a simple tutorial on how to "document.write('Hello World')" would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your function and the object you are using to reveal it dont match.

Comment: Yes, edit {viewAttached: viewAttached} to {viewAttached :attached}

Comment: @JamieHammond Although it's extremely likely that he really means to define the Durandal `attached` handler, so @Craiger, make that `vm = { attached: attached }`.

Comment: @tne That was the point that we were making...

Comment: @PWKad I was implicitly referring to the fact that `viewAttached` is deprecated, although I admit that couldn't have been less clear.

Comment: The problem i have in answering most of these questions is that people dont specify the version of Durandal - I think a lot of people are still using John Papa's Hot Towel template which is the 1.x version which is kinda obsolete now considering the massive changes that 2.0 brought. It would be good if the documentation could go into more detail about attached because i see so many questions around this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly related, but I'd like to add something to what was said in the comments: you most likely shouldn't scan the global document in the `attached` handler.  When it's called, composed views may not be, well, composed/attached themselves yet, and in general it's a good idea not to make assumptions about the global state. Also, you can gain performance by not scanning the whole DOM.

When calling `attached`, [Durandal passes the root DOM element of the view bound to the view model as the first argument to the function](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM/).  Use it to restrict search.  If it's in a child/composed view, use the `compositionComplete` handler, called after all composition in complete (the event "bubbles up").  If it's in a parent view, use the second argument passed to these functions.  If it really sounds too complicated, consider that your design *might* be flawed itself, look for MVVM guidance.

**For completeness:**

The comments mention that

- You must export the right function (`attached` != `viewAttached`),
- If you indeed intended to define an `attached` handler called by Durandal, know that `viewAttached` is deprecated in favor of `attached`.
- And I'd also add that you return an anonymous object containing a `router` property before you return your `vm` (view model for sure), although that might be a left-over from some tests you did and copy-pasted here by mistake.